# What are the differences between the different translations of "Les Animaux dénaturés"?

Tags: translation, les-animaux-denatures

In 1952, Jean Bruller wrote [*Les Animaux dénaturés*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Animaux_d%C3%A9natur%C3%A9s) under his pseudonym, Vercors. According to Wikipedia, the book was translated into English three times:

- [*You Shall Know Them*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20515) (1953)
- [*Borderline*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?909879) (1953)
- [*The Murder of the Missing Link*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?187133) (1958)

Are there any salient differences between the translations? Which one is considered the most authoritative?

Comment: I read this recently after seeing some highly approving comments on it by Alexei Panshin. Yeesh, what a horrible, toxic pile of racist garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, all three of those are using the same translation; the different titles are down to different publishers.

According to ISFDb both [*You Shall Know Them*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20515) and [*Borderline*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?909879) were translated by [Rita Barisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rita_Barisse).  [Vercors](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vercors_(%C3%A9crivain)) was her husband and she translated [many of his works](https://www.amazon.com/Vercors-Translated-Rita-Barisse/s?k=Vercors%20Translated%20By%20Rita%20Barisse).  Given that, we should likely consider this a canonical translation.

This appears to be a case where the same book was published with different titles in the U.S. market (*You Shall Know Them*: [Little, Brown and Company](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/publisher.cgi?248)) and the U.K. market (*Borderline*: [Macmillan and Co.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/publisher.cgi?30790)).

As for [*The Murder of the Missing Link*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?187133), the [linked review](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v63n01_1959-03_EXciter-LennyS/page/n147) has this to say:

> The ridiculous title conceals Vercors' "You Shall Know Them," and has the one beneficial result of giving it a mystery classification, and hence a lower price than SF.

This edition has "(Original title: YOU SHALL KNOW THEM)" on the cover:

[image: Cover of "The Murder of the Missing Link", woman in yellow dress and drawing of a syringe in the background]

(Note that the same reviewer had [previously reviewed](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v53n03_1954-05_cape1736/page/n148) *You Shall Know Them* when it was released, so he would presumably have noted any differences as that would have been germane to his review.)